# Entity Framework 6 and collections

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm developing my first entity-framework app. I'm using EF vesion 6 (from Nuget) and .net 4.0. However, I'm having some difficulty with something that, to me, seems like it should be extraordinarily simple. I've found lots of conflicting advice and solutions on the internet, but after spending several days trying to work things out, I'm really confused and am to the point of questioning some basic understandings I have of the Entity Framework. What I want to do is this: **create a simple collection of related entities, and automatically delete them when they're removed from the parent.**

Here's how I would model this in vanilla C#. In keeping with Microsoft samples, assume we have two classes, Post and Tag, like so:

```
public class Post
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    // Possibly other properties here
}
```

Then, adding a tag is as simple as `myPost.Tags.Add(myTag)` and removing a tag is as simple as `myPost.Tags.Remove(myTag)`.

Now to the Entity Framework side of things: I looked at that and thought "Foreign Key, of course!" but I had a host of issues adding a FK: Tags wouldn't delete from the database when they were removed from the post, `myPost.Tags` would have 0 elements when loaded from the db, despite the SQL explorer showing that the PostId value was correct, etc. I faffled around with a bunch of tricks, like marking the `Tag.PostId` as a Key, manually removing Tags, actually adding Tag to the context as a DbSet, manually setting `myTag.Post = null;` (I tried with Lazy loading both enabled and disabled, for what it's worth - though I'd like to keep it off if possible)

Now (thanks in no small part to seemingly conflicted and overly-complicated examples), I'm quite confused and lost. Can someone tell me exactly how I should go about setting this relationship up in EF? (I'm using Code First, by the way)

## SOLUTION:

Thanks to Moho, I've come up with this structure, which does exactly what I want:

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    public Post()
    {
        Tags = new HashSet<Tag>();
    }
}

public class Tag
{
    [Key, Column(Order=1), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    // Possibly other properties here

    public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order=2)]
    public virtual int PostId { get; set; }
}

public class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

When a `Tag` is removed from a `Post`'s Tags collection, Entity Framework will issue a DELETE for the tag, as outlined here (#2): http://www.kianryan.co.uk/2013/03/orphaned-child/

Likewise, adding a tag to a post will automatically issue an INSERT and set the FK relationship.

One thing to note: Make sure you use `virtual`! I think that was the root of a lot of my frustration as well.

Comment: You didn't put an `Id` property and EF did the relationship? Can you give us an example of how you're doing your queries?

Comment: @Tico I left out EF implementation stuff, which was was intentional - I wanted to avoid any negative effects/preconceptions from my actual implementation (Not to mention it changed quite a bit as I fiddled with it!) so that I might be able to get advice on how to set it up right from the get-go. Same story with my example queries, though I envision my usage case to be like this: "1) Post created with some initial tags 2) Post's tags are edited, some deleted, some added. 3) Post is saved."

Comment: So I'm guessing you're familiar with Context and stuff. Since you do have some data in SQL. Use LINQ to query one of them. If it still returns `null` there might be something wrong with your queries.

Comment: You my friend are an absolute genius! I have been banging my head against the the wall trying to get this work you your solution worked exactly how I wanted it to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try also defining the relationship from the `Tag` side as well, specifying each `Tag` relates to a single `Post` and is required.

Add a required navigation property to `Post` in `Tag`:

```
public class Tag
{
    // you need an ID
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
}
```

Alternatively, if you really don't want to add the navigation property, you can use the Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().HasMany( p => p.Tags ).WithRequired();
```

Comment: I usually add a `Id` for the navigation property.

Comment: I meant you need a primary key ID field for your entities; assumed you left them out for brevity

Comment: The `[Required]` DataAnnotation is used to create a required relationship. What I meant was `public virtual Post Post { get; set; }` and also a property like: `public int PostId { get; set; }`. When I'm searching for an object I only have the `Id`. If I search for a `Post` it'll return `null`

Comment: Would the [Required] annotation also prevent orphaned children (Tags)? Something like in this article: http://www.kianryan.co.uk/2013/03/orphaned-child/  (I tried #2 in my various endeavors)

Comment: yes - making the `Tag`->`Post` relationship required means there can be no `Tag` without a corresponding `Post`.  This is why removing a `Tag` from the `Tags` collection will delete the `Tag` record in the DB

Comment: Correct, @Moho. If you plan to use it Xcelled194, you might want to set cascade delete as false.

Comment: When I try this, the EF throws a `DbEntityValidationException`, complaining that "The Post field is required." instead of deleting the tag. @Tico why's that? Wouldn't that imply that deleting a Post would leave its tags in the database (and in an invalid state)?

Comment: Actually, the default settings is to cascade delete as true. So if you delete a `Post`, all of the `Tags` will be deleted as well, preventing the orphaned children.

Comment: Moho, I've found my solution, which is a slight adaptation of yours. I don't want to post mine as the answer and steal your credit. So I think what I'll do is edit my question to include the solution and mark yours as the answer. If you want to edit your answer a bit to reflect my solution, all the better! :D @Tico That's what I want. (Cascade delete: true)

Comment: Great, @Xcelled194. It's better doing yourself. I bet you learn somethings along the way!

Answer (score 1):

This is probably thread necromancy, but I don't have the rep to just comment. Wouldn't the following do what you need?

```
public class Tag
{
    [Key, Column(Order=1), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    // Possibly other properties here

    public int PostId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PostId")]
    public virtual Post Post { get; set; }

}
```

PostId is loaded from the database, then used as the Foreign Key (via the annotation) into the Post class. Post is virtual, nothing else is.  You could probably just go with the basic [Key] annotation too.

Comment: EF automatically identifies a property named `ID` as the unique identifier for a class, so you're being redundant.  Also, the Fluent API seems to be better (more reliable) at describing relationships than decorations on properties.  Furthermore, defining your relationships in the DbContext (as well as the rest of your persistence description in the other Data Access Layer files) allows you to move away from EF at a later date with only a few changes.